# How to make sure the minidump is already created when the before_send callback is called in sentry-native?

Tags: c++, windows, sentry

```
sentry_value_t before_send(sentry_value_t event, void* hint, void* closure)
{
    // Get files' paths
    CString srcPath = GetSentryDBPath() + "reports\\";
    CString destPath = GetSentryDBPath() + "..\\ACopy.dmp";

    // Get source file's name
    WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd;
    HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFile((srcPath + "*.dmp").GetString(), &ffd);
    if (hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        srcPath += ffd.cFileName;
    }
    FindClose(hFind);

    <more code...>
}
```

In the C++ code (on Windows) above, I'm trying to make a copy of the .dmp file created by Sentry for another internal tool to use. However, I debug it (by logging), and it seems that after my app crashes, when the Sentry's `before_send` callback is called (within the same crashed process), there's no .dmp file created by Sentry's backend (crashpad_handler.exe) yet. Is there any way to force the callback to be called after the .dmp file is created? Or I just can't use the callback to do it at all?